# Getting custom actions from notification

Tags: android, notifications

I use a service that automatically sends me push notifications and I want to automatically press the confirm option of these notifications.  I'm able to capture the notification using the code below:

```
        import android.app.Notification;
        import android.app.PendingIntent;
        import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
        import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

        import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class NotificationHandler extends NotificationListenerService {

    Context context;

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e("STATE","HERE AGAIN");

        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }

    @Override

    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker = "";
        if (sbn.getNotification().tickerText != null) {
            ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        }
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
//        try {
//            //sbn.getNotification().contentIntent.send();
//        } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
        String title = extras.getString("android.title");
        String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
        int id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
        Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;

        Log.i("NEW", "----------");
        Log.i("Package", pack);
        Log.i("Ticker", ticker);
        Log.i("Title", title);
        Log.i("Text", text);
        sbn.getNotification().contentIntent.sen
        for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
            Log.i("Intent", key);
        }
        Log.i("NEW", "----------");


        Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
        msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
        msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
        msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
        msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);
        if (id != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            id.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            msgrcv.putExtra("icon", byteArray);
        }
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);


    }

    @Override

    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("Msg", "Notification Removed");

    }
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to capture the custom option for confirming the notification and then clicking it.  The confirm/deny buttons look [similar to the buttons on this notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4aA8.png).  Any ideas how I can capture this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of actions (if it exists) from the notification by using the following code

```
Notification n = sbn.getNotification();
for(Action action : n.actions){
    String title = action.title.toString;
    ...
}
```

You can create a button with the action-title and then write the code `onClick()` to execute the action corresponding to the notifications.

To be more precise - you can call

```
action.actionIntent.send(); // or another variation of send()
```

from your onClick() on the button to execute the action corresponding to the pendingIntent supplied by the app that sent the notification.